# How can I find the "least common part" among the paths on the same logical drive?

Tags: c++, directory, watch

My program has several paths to be watched, such as
    C:\XML
    C:\MyProg\Raw
    C:\MyProg\Subset\MTSAT
    C:\MyProg\Subset\GOESW
    D:\Dataset\Composite
    D:\Dataset\Global
    E:\Dataset\Mosaic

I want to add 4 paths, namely C:\XML, C:\MyProg, D:\Dataset and E:\Dataset, to my CFolderWatch class instance for the purpose of folder watching insetad of all 7 above-mentioned paths as long as its "Include Subdirectory" switch is set to TRUE. Suppose all paths of being watched have been added to a vector container.

Therefore, my question is: How can I find the "least common part" among the paths on the same logical drive? Thank you in advance!

Detailed explanation to my question:
1. I got some user-defined directories.
2. I want to these directories to be watched. 
3. Before watching, I want to do some preparatory job, for example, find the common part among the path(s) on the same logical drive to avoid possibly adding so many paths to my watching class. For instance, if there are 3 paths on the logical drive C: as follows:
C:\test\Data\R1, C:\test\Data\R2, and C:\test\Data\R3, the common path is "C:\test\Data". So, we should add "C:\test\Data" to the watching module, not the three paths. What I mean the common path here is that it has at least one level of directory. If one path has no common path with the others, just returns unchanged.
4. First thing first, the algorithm should handle different logical drive(s). That is to say, all paths must be classified on the basis of their respective drive letter. Then, find the common path among the passed paths on the same logical drive letter.

Comment: Aren't the least common paths C:\, D:\ and E:\? You might want to refine what that "least common" phrase means to you.

Comment: What's the point of the "Include Subdirectory" switch if both sets of paths are going to lead to identical behaviour? Supposing there are no other sub-folders under the 4 "higher-level" paths that is

Comment: @JB: "least common paths" don't include the case of "logical drive letter" only. for example, "C:\MyProg" is the least common part among the three paths such as C:\MyProg\Raw, C:\MyProg\Subset\MTSAT and C:\MyProg\Subset\GOESW on the same logical drive letter "C:\".

Comment: @ksming: "Include Subdirectory" switch is one of the functionalities of my CFolderWatch class. If set to true, it can watch all sub-directories under the specified directory of being watched.

Answer (score 0):

A two-step algorithm:

1. Partition your directories by drive letter and first directory level.
2. For each partition, keep the longest prefix.

The longest prefix per partition can be easily obtained by counting how many prefix characters each directory has in common with its next sibling, and keeping the minimum.  Using [mismatch](http://cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/mismatch/), for example.

Comment: Thank you very much! But your algorithm is not a "good and generic" one. For example, we have the following paths:
"C:/home/user1/tmp/coverage/test", 
"C:/home/user1/tmp/covert/operator", 
"C:/home/user1/tmp/coven/members

Apparently, "C:/home/user1/tmp" will be expected to be returned, not "C:/home".

Comment: You're not going to have a perfect algorithm until you're able to actually define "least common" instead of saying "your answer isn't it because it fails in such or such case I never told you about beforehand"

Comment: For example, keeping your contrived example, what do you expect to happen if I add C:\home\user1\other\directory? What about C:\home\other\directory? And C:\other\directory?

Comment: I'm very sorry for my phrase "least common". It's somewhat misleading.

Comment: For your above-contrived example, I expect to return C:\home and C:\other\directory.

Answer (score 0):

As JB said I think this is a two step solution and I have tried some basic coding here in C#. If you want it in java I suppose you must be knowing how to use it :)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace So_Try1
{
      class Program
{
    public static int nthOccurrence(String str, char c, int n)
    {
        int pos = str.IndexOf(c, 0);
        while (n-- > 0 && pos != -1)
            pos = str.IndexOf(c, pos + 1);
        return pos;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<String> pathString = new List<string>();
        pathString.Add("C:\\XML");
    pathString.Add("C:\\MyProg\\Raw");
    pathString.Add("C:\\MyProg\\Subset\\MTSAT");
    pathString.Add("C:\\MyProg\\Subset\\GOESW");
        pathString.Add("D:\\Folder2\\Mosaic");
        pathString.Add("D:\\Folder2\\Mosaic\\SubFolder");
        pathString.Add("D:\\Dataset\\Composite");
        pathString.Add("D:\\Dataset\\Global");
        pathString.Add("F:\\Folder1\\Mosaic");
        pathString.Add("H:\\Folder2\\Mosaic");
        pathString.Add("D:\\Folder2\\Mosaic");
        pathString.Add("D:\\Folder2\\Mosaic\\SubFolder");
        pathString.Add("E:\\Dataset\\Mosaic"); 
        Dictionary<String, int> PathDict = new Dictionary<string,int>();

        foreach (String str in pathString)
        {
            int count = 0;
            foreach (char c in str)
                if (c == '\\') count++;
            while (count > 0)
            {
                int index = nthOccurrence(str, '\\', count);
                String tempPath;
                if (index < 0)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine(str);
                    tempPath = str;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine(str.Substring(0,index));
                    tempPath = str.Substring(0, index);
                }

                if (PathDict.ContainsKey(tempPath))
                {
                    PathDict[tempPath]++;
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (var keys in PathDict.Keys)
                    {
                        if (tempPath.IndexOf(keys) > 0)
                        {
                            PathDict[keys]++;
                        }
                    }
                    PathDict.Add(tempPath, 1);
                }
                count--;
            }
        }
        foreach(var keyValue in PathDict){
            if(keyValue.Value > 1)
                Console.WriteLine(keyValue.Key);
            /*Console.WriteLine(keyValue.Key + " - " + keyValue.Value);*/
        }               
    }
}
}
```

This is a very simple program that assumes that you have your paths in a string and checking for duplicates. If for a large no.of paths you must adopt a much more efficient solution.

Comment: I'm not familiar with C# and .NET. Thank you any way.

Comment: C# is just a clone of Java. So I think it should not be a problem if you know Java well.

Comment: Anyways I am having the same doubt as mentioned by @MSalters above. There might be different solutions based upon your question. Can you explain it in a more detailed manner?

Comment: For the input given in my prog the following is the output.

C:\MyProg
C:\MyProg\Subset
D:\Folder2\Mosaic
D:\Folder2
D:\Folder2\Mosaic\SubFolder
D:\Dataset

Comment: I don't want to throw away the path which has no common path with the others. I expect it to be returned unchanged. The purpose of finding any possible "common path" among the user-defined original path(s) is to minimize the number of watching folder(s) by watching their "parent" folder with "Watch Include Subdirectory" switch setting on.

Answer (score 0):

There's no algorithm; you're using inconsistent logic.

Consider just the set

1. C:\XML
2. C:\MyProg\Raw
3. C:\MyProg\Subset\MTSAT
4. C:\MyProg\Subset\GOESW

There are at least 4 different solutions:

1. C:\
2. C:\XML and C:\MyProg\
3. C:\XML , C:\MyProg\Raw and C:\MyProg\Subset
4. C:\XML , C:\MyProg\Raw, C:\MyProg\Subset\MTSAT and C:\MyProg\Subset\GOESW

You fail to explain why 2. is the correct solution. It *is* possible to write an algorithm that finds solution N-1 given solution N as input, so you can get from the input (4) to (1) in three steps. But we don't understand why we should stop at (2).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 1. C:\XML
2. C:\MyProg\Raw
3. C:\MyProg\Subset\MTSAT
4. C:\Myprog\Subset\GOESW

There are only 2 different solutions:
They are: 1. C:\XML and C:\MyProg
2. C:\XML, C:\MyProg and C:\MyProg\Subset

Comment: @GoldenLee: `C:\ ` is the common parent of `C:\XML\ ` and `C:\MyProg\ `, and therefore a solution. Unless there's some "magical" exception to the rule that `Parent\Child1\ ` and `Parent\Child2\ ` cannot be replaced by `Parent\ `, in which case you should have told us.

Comment: Because nobody would like to watch the whole logical drive. As for either only C:\MyProg or both C:\MyProg and C:\MyProg\Subset are watched it depends on user's practical utilization.

Comment: I don't want to throw away the path which has no common path with the others. I expect it to be returned unchanged. The purpose of finding any possible "common path" among the user-defined original path(s) is to minimize the number of watching folder(s) by watching their "parent" folder with "Watch Include Subdirectory" switch setting on.

Comment: @GoldenLee: It's an arbitrary rule, but at least it's a rule. Would have been useful if you had mentioned that. But would people want to watch the whole of `C:\Documents And Settings\ ` ? We really can't guess your precise rules.